# one score at a time, update method

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a simple game with SpriteKit (mostly for learning), and I got a question about score adding. some background: I'm checking if a sprite (SKShapeNode) contains another one, if true, I'm checking their color, if it is the same color, the player should get 1 score. I wrote this function:

```
    func onMatch(){
    for ring in mColorRings {
        if(mPlayer.contains(ring.position)){
                if mPlayer.fillColor.isEqual(ring.fillColor) {
                score += 1
                mScoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works, the problem is, I'm calling this function inside the update method. as the update method runs a lot, it calls my function a lot of time and as long as `mPlayer` contains `ring` it is adding 1 score to the player. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: can you edit the question so it would be clearer what you're asking? What is the update method in your code???

Comment: Your rings could have a variable like: playerHasPassed and change it to true when player passes, then, if playerHasPassed is False you give value, otherwise you don't give the value.

Comment: @Xcoder123 the update method is the default update method in SpriteKit. in there, I'm calling onMatch. the if player contains ring is true from the moment player 'touches' ring until the player passed 'ring' so update method causes a lot of score adding to "score".

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios I will try this solution, thanks.

Comment: @swiftnewbie please check the answer and respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what i suggest:

```
var playerPassed = false

func onMatch(){
    for ring in mColorRings {
        if(mPlayer.contains(ring.position)) {
                if ((mPlayer.fillColor.isEqual(ring.fillColor))  && playerPassed == false) {
                score += 1
                mScoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
                playerPassed = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You're creating a bool and you check if that is **false**(default) and if so, the block executes and when it does, the bool is set to **true** and the condition will be false and no longer return true.

Comment: Thanks, it is possible, I'm only thinking about the next iteration. If I'm checking again, the playerPassed will still be true, if I change it back to false in update, it will enter to the 'if' again and again in the same iteration.

Comment: @swiftnewbie whenever you change the colour, you change the value of the bool

Comment: @swiftnewbie glad it was helpful, if you have trouble with this method on the next iteration, please let me now, and I'll try to be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your game mechanics. If the ring is supposed to give you a score one time then disappear you can safely remove it within that if test. If you want the ring to stay put and maybe be reused later you can add a boolean to the ring class called something like "scoreGiven" and redo your if test to something like this:

```
func onMatch(){
for ring in mColorRings {
    if !ring.scoreGiven{
        if(mPlayer.contains(ring.position)){
            if mPlayer.fillColor.isEqual(ring.fillColor) {
                score += 1
                mScoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
                ring.scoreGiven = true
            }
        }
    }else if(!mPlayer.contains(ring.position)){
        ring.scoreGiven = false
    }
}
```

This is just an example, but note the "not"s in the updated if statements

Comment: Thanks! already got an answer but thanks for the effort and time :).

Comment: @swiftnewbie No problem. I should've probably remarked that the code I provided will set the ring active again once the player moves away from it, other than that it's pretty similar to the other answer that got posted while I was typing